# Can a webform application handle extension less URLS?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Can a webforms application handle extensionless URLS?

The application is running version 4.5

So I want a URL like:

```
www.example.com/login
```

to redirect to the actual page like:

```
www.example.com/users/login.aspx
```

I am ideally looking for a solution that doesn't require any IIS modification ie. application level only

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  There are a bunch of articles that will tell you how.  Here are a couple:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd329551(v=vs.100).aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series